# it didn't work while i replace $cdc_lasutopfhvcZLmcfl to anything try to avoid detected by some site via chromedriver.exe

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i had read this page [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver?answertab=active#tab-top) and i follow the steps in that, but when i finish replace `$cdc_lasutopfhvcZLmcfl` to `whatever_var` , i can't lunch chrome by the driver edited, when i try to lunch it i got an error like this `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)`

it's that because the driver version i used with `ChromeDriver 2.36.540470` ?

when i edit driver in vim after searching the var `$cdc_lasutopfhvcZLmcfl`,
i find the source code was different with the page i mentioned before, it look like this:

```
function getPageCache(opt_doc, opt_w3c) {
  var doc = opt_doc || document;
  var w3c = opt_w3c || false;
  var key = '$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_';
  if (w3c) {
    if (!(key in doc))
      doc[key] = new CacheWithUUID();
    return doc[key];
  } else {
    if (!(key in doc))
      doc[key] = new Cache();
    return doc[key];
  }
}
```

any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 3):

When replacing '$cdc_lasutopfhvcZLmcfl', you must make sure to replace it with a string of the same length (and probably the same structure too). So, you would want to use a replacement that would look like this: '$sws_01234567890123456'. All together, 17 chars after the underscore.